# Most efficient way to perform query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

My goal is to get all records from tables where foreign key values match with IDs returned by a subquery from another table.

I have tried several combinations of but they don't even compile.

To clarify, consider following query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   `news`
WHERE  IDFIRM IN (SELECT ID FROM firm WHERE Block=0)
AND    Actual=1
```

This is a simple query, but besides the `ID` in this subquery, I need to also retrieve other columns and return them in response.

Something like this (but of course this doesn't work):

```sql
SELECT news.*, sub.name
FROM   `news`,
       (SELECT * FROM firm WHERE Block=0) AS sub
WHERE  news.IDFIRM IN (SELECT sub.ID FROM sub)
AND    news.Actual=1
```

I have an idea how to implement this using joins, but the problem is that there can be multiple `IN` statements (from different tables), like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   `news`
WHERE  IDFIRM IN (SELECT ID FROM firm WHERE Block=0)
AND    Actual=1
AND    id_publisher IN (SELECT ID FROM publisher WHERE Block=0)
```

So this query can become quite different, depending on the request.

How can I create the most efficient query to solve this task? Or it is possible only with multiple queries?

Thanks.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Tables? Columns? We can only imagine how many combinations are there. If you want help, be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely use `JOIN` instead of `IN (SELECT ...)`:

#### Query 1:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   `news`
WHERE  IDFIRM IN (SELECT ID FROM firm WHERE Block=0)
AND    Actual=1
```

Replace this by:

```sql
SELECT     news.*
FROM       news
INNER JOIN form ON news.IDFIRM = form.ID
WHERE      news.Actual=1
```

#### Query 2:

```sql
SELECT news.*, sub.name
FROM   `news`,
       (SELECT * FROM firm WHERE Block=0) AS sub
WHERE  news.IDFIRM IN (SELECT sub.ID FROM sub)
AND    news.Actual=1
```

Replace by:

```sql
SELECT     news.*,
           firm.name
FROM       news
INNER JOIN firm ON news.IDFIRM = firm.ID 
WHERE      news.Actual=1
AND        firm.Block=0
```

#### Query 3:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   `news`
WHERE  IDFIRM IN (SELECT ID FROM firm WHERE Block=0)
AND    Actual=1
AND    id_publisher IN (SELECT ID FROM publisher WHERE Block=0)
```

Replace by:

```sql
SELECT     news.*
FROM       news
INNER JOIN firm      ON news.IDFIRM = firm.ID
INNER JOIN publisher ON news.id_publisher = publisher.ID
WHERE      news.Actual=1
AND        firm.Block=0
AND        publisher.Block=0
```

#### Adding tables and conditions

So the idea is that you add all the tables you need with clauses like this:

```sql
INNER JOIN table1 ON news.<foreign-key> = table1.ID
```

and that you add the conditions all in the `WHERE`clause, like this:

```sql
WHERE   table1.field = <literal>
AND     table2.field = <other literal>
AND     ...
```

Comment: Thank you for complete answer, really appreciate this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your your indexes are sane on both sides of the `JOIN` they will  actually be leveraged, whereas subqueries *might* use one side.

```
SELECT [column_list]
FROM news n
  INNER JOIN firm f
    ON n.idfirm = f.id
  INNER JOIN publisher p
    ON n.idpublisher = p.id
WHERE n.actual = 1
  AND f.block = 0
  AND p.block = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already suggesting a JOIN.
You can use multiple JOIN's to get what you want.

```
SELECT * FROM news
JOIN firm ON IDFIRM = firm.ID
WHERE Block = 0
JOIN publisher ON id_publisher = publisher.ID
WHERE Block = 0
```

I'm doing this from memory but should get you close I think.